# max allowed packet keep changing

Tags: mysql

I have a very strange case in mysql 5.5.46. the `max_allowed_packet` keeps resetting to 1024

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1024  |
+--------------------+-------+
```

although it is set in my.cnf to 32M

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

and even if i try to run `set global max_allowed_packet=33554432;` it shows success but does nothing

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=33554432;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1024  |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

when i restart mysql it becomes 32M for a day or two then it back to 1024!! what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some code somewhere is performing `SET @@max_allowed_packet=1024;`.

You could turn on the "general log" to find out where it is coming from.

Comment: i dont think so, max_allowed_packet is readonly variable, and even if i try to set global,,, the value is not affected!

Comment: You can set it for the current connection.  If not; let's see the statements that you executed.  It can be set globally, but only for new connections.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rick James's comment, do note that `max_allowed_packet` is both a general and a session variable. This is why your queries:

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=33554432;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1024  |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

look inconsistent. You set the *global* value but then read the *session* value. Try `show global variables` or `set session max_allowed_packet=?` to get consistent read/write values.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are affected by the zero day recently disclosed?

http://www.zdnet.com/article/zero-day-vulnerability-found-within-mysql-database-application/